# Creating a Javascript Date that is 10 milliseconds after epoch?

Tags: javascript

In Java we can do it like this:

```
new Date(10L);
```

That's 10 milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

[Per the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) docs it does not look like Javascript has a similar constructor.  Do we need to do something like:

```
new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0,10);
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Essentially the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript).

Comment: "10 milliseconds old" means, to me, "10 milliseconds before the present time".  The time 10 milliseconds after the epoch is much more than "10 milliseconds old".

Comment: Good point ... Changed the title.

Comment: Spoken like a gentleman :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that hard:

```
new Date(10);
```

The C-style `L` postfix is not a JavaScript feature, but otherwise `Date()` works as expected.

One of the constructor methods is:

```
new Date(value);
```

Where `value` is specifically defined as:

> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

This is exactly what you're looking for, so it works just like you'd expect from Java.

Comment: I just tried it in a JavaScript console and it worked, so hey.

Comment: @Ole If you're looking at MDN it's the `new Date(value)` example.

Comment: @lonesomeday if only they had said `milliseconds` instead of `value`, allthough I agree that deductively it's kind of obvious.... Anyways we have the full context now.  Happy Halloween guys!

Comment: To be fair, it's a *value* expressed in milliseconds. MDN isn't wrong! You can also give it other types of values.

Comment: @Ole It does describe it as being milliseconds in four different places on that page...

Comment: @lonesomeday that's true, but none of the contexts in the four different places are related to the constructor.  For example it says ... Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC .... But this is not related to what the question is asking.

Comment: The `value` argument is given a very specific definition if you look more closely at the documentation.